# track number of evaluations in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to know how to I track the number of evaluation in knockout observable array for GetArray1() and GetArray2() below.
I have read a sample from this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NCpxm/) but not sure how to fit it into this situation.

```js
var data1 = [{
    "Hours": 1
}, {
    "Hours": 2
}, {
    "Hours": 3
}];


function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.sampleArray = ko.observableArray([]);
  
   var newData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data1)();
    self.GetArray = function() {
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(newData, function (item) {
          self.sampleArray.push(item) //push here
       });
    }
    
    self.GetArray2 = function() {
       $.each(newData, function (index, value) {
          self.sampleArray.push(value) //push here
       });
    }
    
    self.GetArray();
  self.GetArray2();
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach:sampleArray">
    <p data-bind="text:Hours"></p>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to track the number of times `sampleArray` is evaluated? Only computed properties get evaluated automatically. You don't have a computed property,

Comment: everything is there in the link you had . working sample here http://jsfiddle.net/nejdqktq/6/ let us know

Comment: @supercool thanks got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well in the link you provided they are creating a function using `fn` which has the computation logic for getting the `re-evaluation` count

Better way would be using inbuilt functions `isInitial` and `getDependenciesCount` of computed under `computedContext` .

**Logic :**

```
 ko.computed(function () {
     var subscribe = self.sampleArray(); //declared on top to subscribe initially
     if (ko.computedContext.isInitial()) return true;
     var count = ko.computedContext.getDependenciesCount();
     self.revaluationCount(self.revaluationCount() + count);
 });
```

**As per Docs :**

> isInitial() — A function that returns true if called during the first
>   ever evaluation of the current computed observable, or false
>   otherwise. For pure computed observables, isInitial() is always
>   undefined.
>
> getDependenciesCount() — Returns the number of dependencies of the
>   computed observable detected so far during the current evaluation.

Check here for complete **[documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html)** .

working sample with complete code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/j13eustx/)**